# Transparent status bar shows webview content while scrolling IOS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, webview

i have put a webview, Anroid is working fine but on IOS, when i scroll, i see the content scrolling behind the transparent status bar.
[Click and see the top left corner of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spi9F.jpg)

i have tried using safari related css adding margins and paddings but its not working

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        var browser = new WebView();
        browser.Source = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net/";
        Content = browser;
    }
}
```

i expect that the status bar goes opaque and scrolled content doesn't show behind the status bar.

Comment: Hi ,have you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

This reason results from **Safe Area** in IOS devices . Refering to [Safe Area Layout Guide on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) , you can set safe area be `true` in Xamarin Forms:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Safe Area"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <StackLayout>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My content page is as follow :

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var browser = new WebView();
    browser.Source = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/starting-a-test-run";
    Content = browser;
}
```

The final effect :

[image]